# vector related memory allocation question

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am encountering the following bug.

- I have a class `Foo` . Instances of this class are stored in a std::vector `vec` of `class B`.
- in class Foo, I am creating an instance of class A by allocating memory using `new` and deleting that object in `~Foo()`.

the code compiles, but I get a crash at the runtime. If I disable `delete my_a` from desstructor of class `Foo`. The code runs fine (but there is going to be a memory leak).

Could someone please explain what is going wrong here and suggest a fix?

thank you!

```
class A{
      public:
          A(int val);
          ~A(){};
          int val_a;

};

A::A(int val){
       val_a = val;
       };

class Foo {      
      public:
             Foo();
             ~Foo();
             void createA();
             A* my_a;
};

Foo::Foo(){
    createA();
};

void Foo::createA(){
    my_a = new A(20);
};

Foo::~Foo(){
    delete my_a;

};



class B {
      public:
             vector<Foo> vec;             
             void createFoo();            
             B(){};
             ~B(){};
};


void B::createFoo(){
    vec.push_back(Foo());
};


int main(){
    B b;

    int i  =0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
        std::cout<<"\n creating Foo";
        b.createFoo();   
        std::cout<<"\n Foo created";
        }
    std::cout<<"\nDone with Foo creation";

    std::cout << "\nPress RETURN to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator for Foo. Whenever you find you need a destructor, you alnmost certainly need these two as well.  They are used in many places, specifically for putting objects into Standard Library containers.

The copy constructor should look like this:

```
Foo :: Foo( const Foo & f ) : my_a( new A( * f.my_a ) ) {
}
```

and the assignment operator:

```
Foo & Foo :: operator=( const Foo & f ) {
    delete my_a;
    my_a = new A( * f.my_a );
    return * this;
}
```

Or better still, don't create the A instance in the Foo class dynamically:

```
class Foo {      
      public:
             Foo();
             ~Foo();
             void createA();
             A my_a;
};

Foo::Foo() : my_a( 20 ) {
};
```

Comment: Thanks Neil. How should I create instance of class A then? A code snippet would be much appreciated.  Also, how would copy constructur and assignment operator code look like. Thanks very much

Comment: Neil you have a typo ... new A( f.my_a ); -> new A( *f.my_a );

Comment: hi Neil, thanks very much for the code snippet. Actually, I want to pass the `int val` for `my_a` while putting Foo instance in the vector. how do I do that? --> I want something like this: (of course it doesn't work) `vec.push_back(Foo():my_a(40)`

Comment: @memC You ned to give the Foo constructor an integer parameter, which you pass to the A constructor.

Comment: @Neil: oh I see. Thanks . `Foo::Foo(int val):my_a(val)` did it. Thank you

Comment: @Neil, There are a few problems with this code. 1) `new A( f.my_a )` should be `new A( *f.my_a )` in *both* places, 2) The assignment operator does not handle [self-assignment](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-operators.html#faq-12.2).

Comment: @alex I would not in fact write such a simplistic assignment operator myself, so I never test for self assignment in my own code. The code here is pretty obviously not real. I've incorporated your corrections - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify a copy constructor, the compiler makes one for you.  Your compiler-generated copy constructor looks like this:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& copy)
    : my_a(copy.my_a)
{}
```

Woops!  You're copying just the pointer but not the pointed-to memory.  Both your temporary `Foo()` in `createFoo()` and the one copied in to the vector point to the same memory, so the memory is deleted twice, which crashes your program on the second delete.

You should create a copy constructor that looks something like this:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& copy)
    : my_a(new A(*copy.my_a))
{}
```

Note this crashes if `copy` has a NULL `my_a` member, and it also invokes the copy constructor on `A`, which you haven't specified either.  So you'll want to make some further changes.  You'll also want an `operator=` overload too.

Answer (score 2):

The Foo object is copied and at the destruction of every copy, delete is called on the same pointer value my_a.
Implement the copy and assignment operator for Foo or use a smart pointer.

```
 Foo( const Foo& s) : my_a( s.my_a ? new A(*s.my_a) : 0) {
 }

 Foo& operator= (const Foo& s) {
     Foo temp(s); 
     temp.swap (*this);
     return *this;
 }

 void swap (Foo &s) { 
     std::swap (my_a, s.my_a);  
 };
```